# discord.js How do I make the bot work no matter how they write the command, like -piNG

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to find a way to make it that no matter how you write a command in caps or not, it will work, like the -ping command only works like that. If you write -Ping or anything else, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

use the `.toLowerCase()` or `.toUpperCase()` method on the command string, then compare it to an appropriate string (if you lowercase your command string, compare it to a fully lowercased command name visaversa)

Example:

```
const string = 'PiNg';
const command = string.toLowerCase();

console.log(command === 'ping');
// True
```

Comment: Tried this, didn't work. Doesn't show any errors or anything.

Comment: Help us help you — Please provide us with the code you have already tried.

Comment: Its a basic concept, you've messed up somewhere on implementation